# N-Grams with frequency number using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, stringtokenizer, n-gram

I used n-grams tokenizer to create the n-grams in elasticsearch but I can't retrieve the frequency of each gram either bi-gram or tri-gram. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't clear from your question exactly what you were trying to do. It's generally a good idea to post the code you've tried, and as specific a description of your problem as possible.

At any rate, I think this code will come close to doing what you want:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/f357f15360719299ac556e8082afe26e4e0647d1

I started with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387231/multi-word-term-vectors-with-word-ngrams), then refined some using the information in the docs for [shingle token filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html). Here is the mapping I ended up with:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "evolutionAnalyzer": {
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "custom_shingle"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "custom_shingle": {
               "type": "shingle",
               "min_shingle_size": "2",
               "max_shingle_size": "3",
               "filler_token": "",
               "output_unigrams": true
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "content": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "evolutionAnalyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "standard",
               "term_vector": "yes"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Again, be careful using term vectors in production.

Comment: Can you help me to put the aggregations to create the N-grame on All documents instead of one document?

Comment: Assuming what you mean is you want term counts across all your documents, if you use a mapping like the above, you should be able just use a simple [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Here is some updated code: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/6f473fca440e3dcb8e02f3ce2d28131a7f3f7105

Answer (score 0):

You can use [term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html).

Here is some code where I used term vectors in another SO answer:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/3092992993e0328f7c4ee80e768dd508a0bc053f

As a quick example, if I set up an index designed for autocomplete as follows:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "stop",
                  "kstem",
                  "edgengram_filter"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "edgengram_filter": {
               "type": "edgeNGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 15
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "content": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
               "search_analyzer": "standard",
               "term_vector": "yes"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then add a couple of simple docs:

```
POST test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"content":"hello world"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"content":"goodbye world"}
```

I can look at the term frequency for a single document like this:

```
GET /test_index/doc/1/_termvector
```

which returns:

```
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "doc",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "took": 1,
   "term_vectors": {
      "content": {
         "field_statistics": {
            "sum_doc_freq": 8,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sum_ttf": 8
         },
         "terms": {
            "he": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "hel": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "hell": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "hello": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "wo": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "wor": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "worl": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "world": {
               "term_freq": 1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Be careful using term vectors in production, as they do add some overhead. Very useful for testing, though.

**EDIT:** If you're looking for term frequency over the entire index, just use a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Comment: thanks Sloan, but I need n-grams for words not charcters. like that: 

"hello world Sloan" 
I get 
1. hello freq: 1
2. world freq: 1
3. Sloan freq: 1
4. hello world freq: 1
5. world Sloan freq: 1
6. hello world Sloan freq: 1